# Add current folder to reg file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I have the following **reg** file

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Run script]
@="Run &script"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Run script\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\teodora\\Desktop\\test.bat\" \"%1\""
```

How can I add the path of the current folder instead of using **C:\Users...** ? I know how to do this in a **.bat** file but for a **.reg** one doesn't work in the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the current directory in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419868/what-is-the-current-directory-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: @PhotographyBum I need to do this in a .reg file not in a .bat file

Comment: @AlexandraGiurgiteanu, my answer uses a batch file according to the tag you used. Are you telling us that despite using the `[batch-file]` tag, you don't want to use a batch file at all?

Answer (score 3):

Use the variable `%W` which is the working directory.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Run script]
@="Run &script"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\run script\command]
@="cmd /c \"\"%W\\test.bat\" \"%1\"\""
```

Using `%W` instead of a literal absolute path seems to require `cmd /c` as a prefix to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use a reg file, you use `reg.exe` with the `Add` option:

Here's a complete batch file which should do it all for you:

```
@Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\Shell\RunScript" /VE /D "Run &Script" /F >Nul
@Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\Shell\RunScript\command" /VE /D "\"%CD%\test.bat\" \"%%L\"" /F >Nul
```

*Note that this uses the 'current directory' as requested. Adjust `%CD%` accordingly if you no longer want that.*