# Hide Console from Executing CMD /c <executable> On Registry for Context Menu

Tags: console, command, window, registry, contextmenu

I have an executable to work on some data files.  On Windows 10, because of the alias path of the executable, I need to put "CMD /c <executable_path>" on the registry to run the executable from the context menu (ref: [Can't run an EXE from context menu when using ALIAS path in windows registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422884/cant-run-an-exe-from-context-menu-when-using-alias-path-in-windows-registry)).  However, this would show the console window until the executable finishes.  Is there any way to hide the console window during the execution?

I have tried to add "START /b" or "START /min" to the command on the registry, but with those the Windows would pop up a dialog asking me what to do with the selected file.